# How to add menu entry to "Run As"?

Tags: editor, eclipse-plugin

In Plugin Developpment Environnement of Eclipse, How ca i add an menu entry to "Run As" for a specific Editor?

Answer (score 5):

You can get some tips in the Eclipse article:

[**We Have Lift-off: The Launching Framework in Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html)

> **Declaring a launch configuration type**
>
> The first step in creating our applet launcher is declaring a config type, as shown in the following snippet of XML from our plug-in's plugin.xml file:
> Non-UI declaration

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
    <launchConfigurationType
        name="Java Applet"
        delegate="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaAppletLaunchConfigurationDelegate"
        modes="run, debug"               
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet">        
    </launchConfigurationType>
</extension>
```

> The most important part of this declaration is the delegate attribute which specifies the fully-qualified name of a class that implements the interface **`org.eclipse.debug.core.model.ILaunchConfigurationDelegate`**.
> The delegate is the brains of the launcher, and implements the `launch()` method which launches a specified config.

Comment: Is there no way to do this from the Eclipse UI?

Comment: @notfed maybe, but I didn't check with the more recent Eclipse (this answer is five years old)