# How to add new command this?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pde

```
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="newproproject"
               label="My PRO Application Debug"
               style="push">
         </command>
</menuContribution>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uuuH.png]

I want to add new command at red-box.
But i don't know there locationURI.
I was try to do "ALT+Shift+F2".
But i can't know it.

What is there locationUri?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319874/how-to-add-menu-entry-to-run-as

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work this way.

This is another extension point. I also struggeled with this.

It has to look like this:

```
<plugin>
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
    <launchConfigurationType
      delegate="com.example..launch.ExampleLaunchConfigurationDelegate"
      id="com.example.launch"
      modes="run, debug"
      name="MyLauncher">
    </launchConfigurationType>
</extension>
</plugin>
```

You have to Implement *ILaunchConfigurationDelegate* in the Delegateclass.